# CiviQuickbooks extension: How to identify the Redirect URI?

Tags: extension, quickbooks

I'm setting up the CiviQuickbooks extension from Agileware. The docs tell me to enter the Redirect URI into thr quickbooks interface, but there is no obvious URI. How do I find this?

Comment: wonder if it is similar logic to what is used for the xero integration which is explained at https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civixero/blob/master/docs/setup.md

Comment: I've found it by looking at this issue which includes a screenshot of the extension working properly. https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.civiquickbooks/issues/16 In my case this isn't being displayed. No idea why not.